# How do I set the value of a person field with an InfoPath Rule?

Tags: infopath, people-picker

Using InfoPath I can assign a person to a person field set to accept only one person by setting the value of "`AccountID`" for the "`pcPerson`".

In some cases, but not others.

- If the person field contains a person already, the person changes.
- If the person field is blank and I am creating a new item, the person is added.
- If the person field is blank and I am editing an existing item nothing happens.

Is there any way to use an InfoPath rule to add a person to a blank people picker when editing an existing item? I am opening the web form from a SharePoint 2013 server. I am editing the form in InfoPath 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no.

This question is a bit old, but I just spent an afternoon chasing around the exact same thing. OP described the scenario perfectly, and having read a dozen different posts on the topic, it is just one of those odd things that SharePoint 2013 + InfoPath 2010 cannot do via rules.

I went to Designer for my need. You can use text fields on the form and then copy them into the actual People fields via Workflow when the record is saved. It's not optimal, but it's done.

For whoever else is looking, don't beat your head against this wall. Find a way around.

Comment: So far my work around has been to be sure the form assigns a person to the field initially as I don't have access to designer this  environment. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

A little more simple solution could be, to insure the field is filled since first load, but hidden for the time you don´t need it. Only if you want to fill it with serious information unhide it and fill with correct information. So you make sure, you only Change the Field since the first load. This could be a workarround. In my case, it was helpfull.